# Stackdriver latency for monitoring google cloud pub/sub

Tags: monitoring, latency, google-cloud-pubsub, stackdriver

Documented from https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/metrics#time-series

> Metric data is collected on schedules that vary across monitored resources. Some data is regularly "pulled" by Stackdriver Monitoring from the monitored resources, and some data is "pushed" by applications, services, or the Stackdriver Monitoring agent.

I'd like to know how stackdriver collects data from Google Cloud Pub/Sub, what is the promised latency bound? I've tried creating a topic/subscription and publishing messages and watch how long until the metrics logged in stackdriver. On average it's about 1-2 minutes, but sometimes very slow, up to 5-8 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

We don't currently document what the expectations are for this, in part because there's not a single answer and it depends on different factors. But we are aware that this is important to have, and are working on a clear way to communicate it. Stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Looking forward to it!